# How can I remove all animations on Samsung One UI (Android 9)?

Tags: 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9, samsung-one-ui

How can I remove all animations on Samsung One UI (Android 9)?

I've only found:

[image: ?]

which does reduce the animations but does not remove them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting to remove the animations on:

`Settings -> Accessibility -> Visibility enhancements -> Remove animations`:

[image]

I have no idea why this is in a different place, and why animations are turned on by default (this is a waste of time).